# Failing to change my keymap for X11 on void linux

Tags: xorg, xkb, void-linux

I have installed a recent version of void linux on a Fujitsu Lifebook E751.

- uname -a results in 4.12.11_1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Sep 8 20:17:18 UTC 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux.
- Xorg version is 1.19.3, Protocol Ver. 11

After installations I had a us keyboard mapping. This is driving me nuts, hence I tried to change it by writing several variants of a /etc/X11/xorg.conf. None worked.

After consulting google several times I followed the official Xorg guide. I concocted this configuration:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "system-keyboard"
    MatchIsKeyboard "on"
    Option "XkbLayout" "neo"
    Option "XkbModel" "pc105"
EndSection
```

But despite all efforts, the problem stays the same. I get

```
(EE) Error loading keymap /var/lib/xkb/server-0.xkm
(EE) XKB: Failed to load keymap. Loading default keymap instead.
```

In the end the US-keyboard is loaded. 
This is driving me totally nuts!

Comment: I don't know how Void Linux handles it, but (1) `/var/lib/xkb/server-0.xkm` doesn't exist on my system. In fact `/var/lib/xkb` is mostly empty, the rules are in `/usr/share/X11/xkb`, (2) "neo" isn't one of the default layouts, I would have to add it by hand. So googling isn't going to help, you need to figure out how your `xkb` is set up, and why it is different. Look at `setxkbmap`, `xkbcomp`, and `xkbprint`, and [here](https://www.x.org/archive//X11R7.7-RC1/doc/xorg-docs/input/XKB-Config.html). Identify where your xkb files are.

Comment: `/var/lib/xkb` is essentially a cache for precompiled XKB keymaps and should not be the problem here.  unless you've added `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/neo` to your system, you probably don't have a `neo` **layout** available.  on my system, `neo` is a **variant** of the `de` **layout**.  to test: `setxkbmap -layout de -variant neo` (in an xterm) and see if that gets where you're trying to go.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a line like this in your /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-keyboard.conf or xorg.conf config file for example:

```
MatchProduct "AT Translated Set 2"
```

Your product could be different so check /var/log/Xorg.0.log for the details.

There are a lot of things that can match a keyboard so the MatchProduct narrows down the choices for the Xserver.

Check the man page xkeyboard-config for info about the layout.